# How to get parts of char* string

Tags: c++

I have a device that sends serial data to my esp8266.

I need to parse that data to my application.
The format of each line I receive from the serial port is like this:

```
"\x02""Q,328,013.83,N,00,\x03""1D"
```

where the 1st character is char 2 (start of transmission) and the 3rd from the end is char 3 (end of transmission). The last number ("1C") is the checksum.
The numbers between, are the values I want to parse.

I 've written the following code which works, but I wonder if this the correct way of doing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

uint16_t calcCRC(char* str)
{
  uint16_t crc=0; // starting value as you like, must be the same before each calculation
  for (uint16_t i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) // for each character in the string
  {
    crc ^= str[i]; // update the crc value
  }
  printf("CRC: %X\n", crc);
  return crc;
}

int main()
{
    char * data= "\x02""Q,328,013.83,N,00,\x03""1D";

    const char start = 2; //stx start transmission
    const char end   = 3; //etx end transmission
    char* pos1 = strchr(data, start);
    char* pos2 = strchr(data, end);
    int p1,p2;
    if (pos1 && pos2) {
        p1 = pos1-data+1;
        p2 = pos2-data+1;
        printf ("found at %d, %d\n", p1, p2);   
    } else
    return 0;

    char* checksumStr;
    checksumStr = strrchr(data, end);
    int checksum = 0;
    if (checksumStr) {
        checksum = strtol(checksumStr+1, NULL, 16);    
    }

    printf("checksum char: |%s| check number %X\n", checksumStr+1, checksum);

    char cleanData[25];
    strncpy(cleanData, data+p1, p2-p1-1);
    cleanData[p2-p1-1] = '\0';

    uint16_t crc = calcCRC(cleanData);
    printf("Clean data to checksum: |%s|\n", cleanData);

    char* addr = strtok(cleanData, ",");          // Q
    int WindDir = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));        // 328
    float WindSpeed = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));    // 13.83
    char* unit = strtok(NULL, ",");               // N
    char* deviceStatus = strtok(NULL,",");        // 00


    printf("CRC: %X, Speed %3.2f, dir %d, ", crc, WindSpeed, WindDir);

    return(0);
}
```

[Run it here](https://paiza.io/projects/e/LgRGYw2r3gNwIKs6e_HUZA)

Thank you !!

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`? Tags says `C++` code says `C` (only first line is `C++` specific).

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::istringstream`. Don't hold on to old C stuff.

Comment: Note: The above-mentioned characters (chr 2 and chr 3) do not appear in the text written here. Probably the editor does not accept them. But you can see them if you click the link to run the code.

Comment: If this is `C++` what version you can use?

Comment: I am using vscode + platformio that uses arduino libraries. I think it is C++11

Comment: Is the `'00'` a single *nul-character* or `"00"` two ASCII zeros? It you were going to take a C approach, then a simple single call to `sscanf` would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your code into two parts:

- **Message extraction** – extracts the actual message from buffer and checks the checksum.
- **Message processing** – converts the message to tokens which then can be easily take care of and extracts the information.

Your **calling** code should look like this:

```
// extract the message
char msg[ 1024 ];
if ( !extract_message( msg, data ) )
  return false;

// process the message
int dir;
double speed;
process_message( msg, dir, speed );
```

A message **extraction** function idea:

```
#define STX '\x02'
#define ETX '\x03'

bool extract_message( char* d, const char* s )
{
  // start of text
  if ( *s != STX )
    return false;
  ++s;

  // actual message
  char cs = 0; // checksum
  while ( *s && ETX != *s )
  {
    cs ^= *s;
    *d++ = *s++;
  }
  *(d-1) = '\0';

  // end of text
  if ( *s != ETX )
    return false;
  ++s;

  // sent checksum
  char scs = (char)strtol( s, 0, 16 );

  //
  return scs == cs;
}
```

A **processing** function idea:

```
#define MAX_TOKENS 5

bool process_message(char* buf, int& dir, double& speed) // assumes the message is correct
{
  // breaks the input into tokens (see strtok)
  const char* delim = ",";
  const char* tokens[ MAX_TOKENS ];
  int token_count = 0;
  for ( char* cursor = strtok( buf, delim ); cursor; cursor = strtok( 0, delim ) )
  {
    tokens[ token_count ] = cursor;
    ++token_count;
  }

  // ...

  dir = atoi( tokens[ 1 ] ); // assumes the token is valid
  speed = atof( tokens[ 2 ] ); // assumes the token is valid

  //
  return true;
}
```

I do not have a handy Arduino compiler, so the code might need some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you @zdf Your code compiles and works perfectly in Arduino. In fact, I was thinking to use sscanf mentioned earlier but sscanf produces larger code which is something that I don't want for such a low memory device.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works well, it's fine, but I recommend to you to write C++ style codes. I wrote part of your code in C++. I believe you can understand how to read the rest of your data using istream.

I also hope you perfer using std::string than const char*, use std::iostream to get or put data from and to. There's more flexible way to split strings using std::regex but I think it's too hard to understand currently.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string data = "Q,328,013.83,N,00,1D";
    istringstream iss(data);

    string tmp;
    int wind_dir;
    float wind_speed;

    getline(iss, tmp, ','); // read until ','
    iss >> wind_dir;

    getline(iss, tmp, ','); // read until ','
    iss >> wind_speed;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I executed and found that wind_dir and wind_speed were set to 328 and 13.82999 in VS2019. Hope you try to get the rest of data.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are asking. When you say:

> I've written the following code which works, ...

There is no way the code as written above can work. You do not have the control characters `2` (ASCII `stx` - start transmission) or `3` (ASCII `etx` - end transmission) embedded in `data`, so your conditional `if (pos1 && pos2)` tests `false` and you exit with `return 0;` (normally `return 1;` is used to indicate error, that is the value of `EXIT_FAILURE`)

To make your code work and include `stx` at the beginning of `data` and `etx` at the end, you can do:

```
    char data[32] = "";
    char stx[2] = { 2 };
    char etx[2] = { 3 };
    char *serial= "Q,328,013.83,N,00,1D";
    strcat (data, stx);
    strcat (data, serial);
    strcat (data, etx);
```

That now provides `data` in a form where `strchr(data, start);` and `strchr(data, end);` will properly locate the start and end of the serial data in the example.

The remainder of your code DOES work, though note all your variables `addr`, `WinDir`, `WindSpeed`, `unit` and `deviceStatus` are pointers to address within `cleanData` and are only valid while `cleanData` remains in scope. That is fine here as your code ends thereafter, but if you intend to do this within a function and want to return the values, then you will need to provide storage for each and copy each to storage that will remain valid after `cleanData` has gone out of scope.

Currently `addr`, `unit` and `deviceStatus` are unused in your code. You can write a short `printf` to output their values to have your code compile cleanly, without warning (you can also cast to `(void*)`, but I'm not positive that is supported on Arduino). Adding a short `printf` solves the warning issue and gives you a look at all the data parse from `cleanData`, e.g.

```
    printf ("\naddr         : %s\n"
            "WinDir       : %d\n"
            "WindSpeed    : %.2f\n"
            "unit         : %s\n"
            "deviceStatus : %s\n\n", 
            addr, WindDir, WindSpeed, unit, deviceStatus);
```

With that, your code compiles cleanly and does work (though you need a final `'\n'` at the end of `printf("CRC: %X, Speed %3.2f, dir %d, ", crc, WindSpeed, WindDir);` (or a simple `putchar ('\n');` for your code to be POSIX compliant.

I'm not sure if the embedded `stx` and `etx` were your stumbling blocks or not, that's not 100% clear from the question, but without them the code does not work. Let me know if you have further questions.

---

**After Question Update**

If you are looking for an alternative to parsing the data, you could declare `addr`, `unit` and `devicestatus` a short character arrays, e.g. `char [16]` (or whatever the longest is), and then simply use `sscanf` to parse `data` directly, e.g.

```
    if (sscanf (data, "\x02 %15[^,],%d,%f, %15[^,], %15[^,], \x03",
                addr, &winddir, &windspeed, unit, devicestatus) != 5) {
        fputs ("error parsing data.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

`sscanf` can adequately handle the embedded `stx` and `etx`. A minimal example using `sscanf` on `data` directly could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MINSTR 16

int main (void) {

    char *data = "\x02""Q,328,013.83,N,00,\x03""1D",
        addr[MINSTR],
        unit[MINSTR],
        devicestatus[MINSTR];

    int winddir;
    float windspeed;

    if (sscanf (data, "\x02 %15[^,],%d,%f, %15[^,], %15[^,], \x03",
                addr, &winddir, &windspeed, unit, devicestatus) != 5) {
        fputs ("error parsing data.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("addr         : %s\n"
            "windir       : %d\n"
            "windspeed    : %.2f\n"
            "unit         : %s\n"
            "devicestatus : %s\n", addr, winddir, windspeed, unit, devicestatus);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/windspeed+dir
addr         : Q
windir       : 328
windspeed    : 13.83
unit         : N
devicestatus : 00
```

Comment: The link does contain the control characters. Paste typo, probably.

Comment: Yes exactly. As I noted below my post the control characters exist, but they do not show here. Thank you @zdf for the edit.

Comment: My bad, nothing I could copy/paste from the question - no matter how hard I tried.

Comment: Only other note would be the `'*'` generally goes with the *variable* not the *type*. Why? `char* a, b, c;` certainly does NOT declare three pointers to `char`, instead it declares a single pointer and two character variables. `char *a, b, c;` makes that clear.

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin for the answer. Although it does not solve my real problem (it does not check for checksum), it answers my question about extracting values from the char * string. I will try to modify your solution with sscanf to my own needs.